# How to add spacing between UIButtons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton

I'm adding a series of UIButtons with an Array using the following code. I was wondering if there was a way to add some spacing between each of the buttons as they are currently too close together.

here's my code and thanks for any help:

```
 // Create buttons for the sliding category menu.
    buttonArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    myImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"category-cafe-unsel.png", @"category-food-unsel.png", @"category-clothing-unsel.png", @"category-health-unsel.png", @"category-tech-unsel_phone.png" , @"category-tech2-unsel.png", @"catefory-theatre-unsel.png", @"category-travel-unsel.png", nil];

    myImagesSel = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"category-cafe-sel.png", @"category-food-sel.png", @"category-clothing-sel.png", @"category-health-sel.png", @"category-tech-sel_phone.png" , @"category-tech2-sel.png", @"catefory-theatre-sel.png", @"category-travel-sel.png", nil];

    // only create the amount of buttons based on the image array count
    for(int i = 0;i < [myImages count]; i++)
    {
        // Custom UIButton

        btn.tag  = i+1;

        btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

        [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 20.0f, 52.0f, 52.0f)];
        [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %d", i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[myImages objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[myImagesSel objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

        NSLog(@"The button title is %@ ", btn.titleLabel.text);

        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [buttonArray addObject:btn];


     //   NSLog(@"Button tag is: %d",btn.tag);

    }

    UIImageView *blackColor = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blackColor.png"]];


    // initialize the slide menu by passing a suitable frame, background color and an array of buttons.
    slideMenuView = [[SlideMenuView alloc] initWithFrameColorAndButtons:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 80.0f) backgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]  buttons:buttonArray];
```

Comment: you have set the frame of all button same thats why you may be getting buttons overlapping each other

Comment: thanks. they aren't overlapping, just too close. I just need a 5pixel space between each. any idea how I might go about doing that? :)

Comment: Horizontaly or vertically ? Also if you are using the above code the buttons will overlap as said by @Leena

Comment: i think spacing will dependent on slideMenuView and you are drawing button in slideMenuView....

Comment: you need horizontal or vertical gap in between buttons?

Comment: @Leena horizontal spacing only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: `[btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, i*25.0f, 52.0f, 52.0f)];` You ll get 5 pix gap between buttons

Comment: thanks, but that had a strange vertical effect instead

Comment: this code sample allows you to place your buttons in one vertical line. i*25.0f means next button Y location. You may also change X location by passing this expression as first argument instead. Also you may change from 25.0f to any other value to shift next button bottom or right

Comment: I tried that but nothing happened to the X value

Comment: Sorry)) I didn't look at the last line of your code. I see You are using thirdparty "SlideMenuView"You should fix this class instead fixing that all said. Are  you using the last sources?

Comment: the latest code from [here](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-myshoes-app/source/browse/trunk/MyShoes/Classes/SlideMenuView.m?spec=svn23&r=23) should act like you need

Comment: that was it! thanks for finding that. you have good eyes! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

Vertical spacing:

```
 [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, (20.0f + ((52.0 * i) +5)), 52.0f, 52.0f)];
```

Horizontal spacing

```
if(i==0)
{
   [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 52.0, 52.0f, 52.0f)];
}
else
{
   [btn setFrame:CGRectMake((52.0+(52.0 * i)+5), 52.0, 52.0f, 52.0f)];
}
```

Comment: @hanumanDev: that was a typo, fixed it !

Comment: thanks, but that moved the unbutton series down and did not add spacing between each of the individual buttons (the horizontal is the one I'm using) :)

Comment: the buttons were pushed down because of the 52.0 as the Y value instead of 20. I changed that, however the button spacing is still not showing

Comment: @hanumanDev: thanks for the comment, I found the issue also fixed it

Comment: @hanumanDev: still have issues ?

Comment: there were some syntax issues - some missing ( )'s. Still the spacing doesn't work though. I changed it to  if(i==0)
            {
                [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0, 52.0f, 52.0f)];
                        }
                        else
                {
                    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake((52.0+((52.0 * i)+5)), 20.0, 52.0f, 52.0f)];
                }

Answer (score 0):

try this :-

[btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f+54*i , 20.0f, 52.0f, 52.0f)];